# How do I delete a default AKS node pool when I get an error saying it's the "backend address pool of the basic load balancer"

Tags: kubernetes, azure, azure-kubernetes-service

I'm attempting to replace a node pool in Azure Kubernetes Service with a new pool (that has a larger VM size).  The current pool was deployed using an [ARM template](https://github.com/NickGraham101/dfc-devops/blob/58925ca008b4a80946840dec95d09b2d6d958327/ArmTemplates/aks.json) that uses version 2019-06-01 of the resource manager API.  As per the [Microsoft documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/use-system-pools#delete-a-system-node-pool) I should be able to add a new System node pool and delete the original, default node pool.

I can successfully deploy an additional node pool that has it's mode set to System using [this template](https://github.com/NickGraham101/dfc-devops/blob/e0a896afdbc6dbf1447986078930a4f391cac931/ArmTemplates/aks.json), that template uses version 2020-03-01 of the resource manager API so that I can set the mode of the new pool.

When I attempt to delete the original, default node pool using `az aks nodepool delete -g gandt-testshared-rg --cluster-name gandt-testshared-aks -n agentpool` I get an error saying `Operation failed with status: 'Bad Request'. Details: The agent pool cannot be deleted because it is used as the backend address pool of the basic load balancer.`.

Why am I getting this error and what can I do to get the backend address pool of the basic load balancer to use the new node pool?

**Update**

I've deleted the cluster and redeployed using the original ARM template then added the 2nd node pool using az cli command `az aks nodepool add -g gandt-testshared-rg --cluster-name gandt-testshared-aks --name poolb2ms01 --node-count 1 --node-vm-size Standard_B2ms --mode System` and got the same result when deleting the default node pool

Comment: did you try to create a loadbalancer service before trying to delete the bakend nodepool? and what version of k8s cluster do you use?

Comment: The cluster has a couple of loadbalancer services.  The Kubernetes version at the time was 1.15.7.  I've since had to just delete my cluster, accept the downtime and redeploy a fresh cluster with the latest version of the resource manager API and the larger VM size

Answer (score 1):

If my assumption is correct that's related to having a loadbalancer that wasn't correctly deleted.
Which could be resulted by redeploying a service (of type: load balancer) in a short time before Azure cleans up the previously associated loadbalancer resource.

To my knowledge, that could be fixed with the rolling of [Kubernetes 1.17](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG/CHANGELOG-1.17.md) and the Loadbalancer Finalizer feature, [through this pull](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/78262).

please update the question if that showed up with the new cluster version.